# Is it possible to change tableView.backgroundView frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to put my table view background below the nav bar. When I try to change frame nothing happens..

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, -100, 320, 480)];
 imageView.image = self.theme.bgImage;
 [self.tableView setBackgroundView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the docs it says:

> A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the
>   size of the table view.

So I think it's alway resized again by the framework.

Answer (score -1):

Add UIImageview as subview to view and set appropriate image.Place imageview behind tableview. Make tableview background nil. Then try to change frame. This may help you.